# Unity Asset Bundles backward compatibility

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

I am working in a project, and we use Unity3D ... we are loading our Asset Bundles Dynamically. But we want to add the backward compatibility between the versions of our app.

Let's say that I release version 1.05.0 and the user loaded a certain Asset Bundle, After that the user downloaded version 1.06.0 which contains some changes in some scripts that were used in version 1.05.0

Could I make version 1.06.0 work with the same Asset Bundle of version 1.05.0 ?!
 or that is not doable ?!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

"Some changes in some scripts" is quite vague.

Generally speaking, asset bundles do not include scripts directly, but they do include references to scripts (which may be corrupted if you move your scripts) and to properties (which may get complicated if you refactor). [Unity Answers does have some more detailed information.](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/175310/how-to-maintain-asset-bundle-compatibility.html)

If all you did was some minor tweak to the `Update()` function of some script, you should be fine.

If you renamed your scripts or moved scripts between assemblies, you will likely have a problem.

If you create new serialized fields, an older asset bundle will not contain those fields, and they will receive their default value upon instantiation.

If you remove existing serialized fields, they will be ignored upon instantiation.

If you rename or change the type of existing serialized fields, Unity will "try" to reconcile that, but I wouldn't count on it working.

If you're looking for a more robust system, you might be better off attaching "plain old data" components just to serialize your data, then using that data to reconstruct your assets at runtime.

Comment: Firstly, Thanks for your help.
Secondly, I mean changes (add or remove fields) ... how could I make the backward compatibility for Asset Bundles in this case ?!

Comment: And please could you explain to me what do you mean by your idea for more robust system ?

Comment: Like I mentioned: a field removed in later versions will be ignored, while a field added in later versions will end up with its default value. As far as a more robust system, I'm referring to anything that partially or completely bypasses Unity's built-in serialization in favor of putting together something *you* control.